# In DotnetNuke , how can we make manageable footer area per portal

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning, dotnetnuke-5

I am using DotnetNuke 5.4 Community and I have met with a specific requirement.

I need to make it possible a configurable footer area (i.e a DNN admin should be able to manage the content & image to be displayed in footer area) on a portal basis.

As now I can change the header logo on portal basis, the same functionality need to be extended to the footer area.

**Q1.) Is there any skin object that satisfies my current requirement?**

**Q2.) In the copyright text I am limited to enter only 100 characters.But I need to extent it to 250 chars.What can I do about this.**

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks,

Balu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need custom skin objects.
I will do this in following way:

create a table called:

```
create table projectSettings(
projectSettingId bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key, 
portalId int ,
settingName varchar(100),
setttingValue varchar(max)
)
-- name looks odd, but don't use siteSettings, portalSettings, HostSettings etc 
-- because it may be possible that they are already exists in dnn
```

Create entries for all the things you want in footer like, copy right, and any other setting you want

create a custom skin object that will accept portalId and SettingKey as property and show the settingValue based on query.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.It is more elegant and futuristic, however I was bit reluctant in adding another table to the CMS.Instead i retained an skin object which fetch details from an XML.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  You can't add additional settings into the settings area so you would need to do some custom work to accomplish this. Depending on how savvy your user is they could put an HTML module in a footer pane and mark it 'display on all pages'

But I imagine you are looking for something more elegant than this.

Comment: Yes, my client is holding multiple portals with copyright and footer different, and he does not feel so comfortable in configuring the text module for each.So i decided to develop a skin object as suggested above.But adding a text module is a great thought, thanks.